# Distance UTC - LocalTime on Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, utc, dst

I am writing a Linux (Ubuntu and Debian Lenny) application in C++.

Now I need to know the distance/offset between UTC and the currently set system time at a given day in the past. Since I need to convert recorded data, I the distance need to be calculated with respect to a date in the past (which may have a different DST setting than the current day).

Anyone know how to do this?

Edit: Reading the first answer I think I was misunderstood: I do not want to compare dates/times. I have date/time values which I want to convert from UTC to local time.

Comment: one issue you may have with this is the variance of the local time vs UTC based on varying daylight saving time laws

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepare the tm structure with date:

```
struct tm date;
memset(&date,0,sizeof(date));
date.tm_year = year - 1900;
date.tm_mon = month - 1;
date.tm_mday = day;
date.tm_hour = hour;
date.tm_min = minute;
date.tm_sec = second;
date.tm_isdst = -1; // VERY IMPORTANT

mktime(&date); /// fill rest of fields
```

And then take a look on `tm_gmtoff`

```
printf("%d\n",date.tm_gmtoff);
```

This is distance from UTC.

Now this is Linux and BSD specific, it would not work on other stystems, and this works
with respect to DST.

Read man mktime for more information. And filling `struct tm` with correct values

P.S.: Converting from UTC to Local and back?

```
time_t posix_time = timegm(&UTC_Filled_struct_tm); // Linux specific line
localtime_r(&posix_time,&local_Filled_struct_tm);
```

Local to UTC

```
time_t posix_time = mktime(&local_Filled_struct_tm);
gmtime_r(&posix_time,&UTC_Filled_struct_tm);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you may benefit from using Boost.DateTime or [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

As for Boost.DateTime tt might be like this:

1) You prepare a database with timezone information [Boost.Datetime](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/date_time/local_time.html) and create a timezone. Timezones are important since they hold information about DST

```
tz_database tz_db;
tz_db.load_from_file("./date_time_zonespec.csv");
time_zone_ptr nyc = tz_db.time_zone_from_region("America/New_York"); // or other timezone
```

Or just create a timezone like this.

```
std::string kaliningrad_string = "EET+02:00:00EEST+01:00:00,M3.5.0/02:00:00,M10.5.0/03:00:00";
boost::local_time::time_zone_ptr kaliningrad_tzone_posix(new boost::local_time::posix_time_zone(kaliningrad_string));
std::string vladivostok_string = "VLAT+10:00:00VLAST+01:00:00,M3.5.0/02:00:00,M10.5.0/03:00:00";
boost::local_time::time_zone_ptr vladivostok_tzone_posix(new boost::local_time::posix_time_zone(vladivostok_string));
```

Creating timezones using a string specification of timezones looks more difficult but you can make use of it if you can't find a particular timezone in date_time_zonespec.csv. 
For example Samara used to be in UTC+4 before March 2010 and now it is in UTC+3. `date_time_zonespec.csv` doesn't have history of changes, so in this situation it is necessary to create a timezone out of the string specification. However I recall that ICU seems to have timezones with this sort of history [ICU TimeZone Classes](http://userguide.icu-project.org/datetime/timezone):

> Time zone data changes often in
>   response to governments around the
>   world changing their local rules and
>   the areas where they apply. The ICU
>   time zone data is updated for each
>   release, and the easiest way to stay
>   up to date may be to upgrade to the
>   latest ICU release, which also
>   provides bug fixes, code improvements
>   and additional features.

3) Make a localtime you need, for example

```
local_date_time tmp(boost::gregorian::date(2010, 3, 28), boost::posix_time::time_duration(1,59,0),nyc, boost::local_time::local_date_time::EXCEPTION_ON_ERROR);
```

4) And then calculate difference using functions `utc_time` and `local_time`
There is an example on that page:

```
ptime pt(date(2004,Nov,5), 
         hours(10));
time_zone_ptr zone(new posix_time_zone("MST-07"));
local_date_time az(pt, zone);
az.utc_time(); // 10am 2004-Nov-5
az.local_time(); // 3am 2004-Nov-5
```

5) Another example. The local time is the same but UTC is different

```
local_date_time tmp(boost::gregorian::date(2010, 3, 28), boost::posix_time::time_duration(1,59,0),kaliningrad_tzone_posix, boost::local_time::local_date_time::EXCEPTION_ON_ERROR);
std::cout << "As is: " << tmp << ", UTC: "  << tmp.utc_time() << std::endl;

local_date_time tmp(boost::gregorian::date(2010, 3, 28), boost::posix_time::time_duration(1,59,0),vladivostok_tzone_posix, boost::local_time::local_date_time::EXCEPTION_ON_ERROR);
std::cout << "As is: " << tmp << ", UTC: "  << tmp.utc_time() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the times are converted to UTC (see `mktime()` for example). You then can use either [difftime()](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Elapsed-Time.html) or the timeval_subtract example function from the same link, depending on what structure the times are stored in.